# orange artifact moves with screen

Tags: artifacts

i was trying to bevel something and this orange speck appeared when i ctrl z back. i cannot get it to go away and reload its still there it does not show up in a new file, it looks like 3 pixels, but it stays relative to whatever view. when i move my view it stay exactly in the same spot in the screen view, so i don't think it is anything in the scene. not sure what did it or how to get rid of it, i looked around on here and other online places but cant seem to find out anything? attached is a pic sorry both screen are on the screenshot im new to this, and the artifact is near the handle, it is not an origin dot[image]

Comment: What happens if you close Blender and reopen a new session?

Comment: Try tabbing into edit mode with your handle object. You may have accidentally added an additional floating face to that object, so if it's still there in edit mode, select it and delete it.

Comment: now its not there, a new file does not have it and it cannot be deleted. However now there is a white plus sign+ exactly where the speck was. dont know if its related? when i put my cursor on the plus sign it changes to a crosshair and has a x on it also and moving over to the corner of the plus shows a corner boarder. edit i can move the plus sign though